# OkHttp how to skip the FormBody form elements encoding

Tags: java, encode, okhttp, skip

I need to make an HTTP request with some parameters in the body. I need to pass the string **"set(1,2,3)"** as is, or at least the commas (,) should be unchanged. Unfortunately, OkHttp 4.9.1 encodes my strings regardless of using FormBody.Builder's `add` or `addEncoded` methods.
How can I avoid it?

The sample code:

```java
package my;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.FormBody;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okio.Buffer;

public class Check {

  public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final String value = "set(_1_,_2_,_3_)";
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url("http://localhost")
      .header("Authorization", "Bearer redacted")
      .post(new FormBody.Builder()
        .add("key", value)
        .addEncoded("key_encoded", value)
        .build())
      .build();
    final Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
    request.body().writeTo(buffer);
    System.out.println(String.format(
      "Request body (Content-Type: \"%s\") is \"%s\"",
      request.body().contentType(), buffer.readUtf8()
    ));
  }

}
```

The result is:

`Request body (Content-Type: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") is "key=set%28_1_%2C_2_%2C_3_%29&key_encoded=set%28_1_%2C_2_%2C_3_%29"`

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved by skipping use the **FormBody** at all.
To build the HTTP body, the **RequestBody.Companion.*create*** static method is used:

```java
RequestBody.Companion.create(bodyString, MediaType.get("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
```

The *bodyString* is a pre-encoded body string (`key1=value1&key2=value2...`).